# Proof of ${n \choose 0},{n \choose 1},{n \choose 2},...,{n \choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ is monotonically increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that for $n>1$, sequence $${n \choose 0},{n \choose 1},{n \choose 2},...,{n \choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}$$ is strictly monotonically increasing.

If I will show, that $${n \choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}-{n \choose \lfloor n/2-1\rfloor} >0$$ will that  be the end of proof?

Comment: No. You have to show that for any $0\leq k<\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1$ you have $$ {n\choose k} < {n\choose k+1}$$

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Prove that $\dfrac{n\choose k}{n\choose k+1} < 1$. There'll lots of cancellation.

Comment: Ok. I proved it. However I didn't use assume that $0\leq k<\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1$. Is it the end of proof?

Comment: Because for $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1$, ${n\choose k} \le {n\choose k+1}$, and the sequence must be strictly monotonically increasing. Sorry, I've forgotten to write this.

Comment: Why is $k=\left \lfloor{n\over 2}\right \rfloor-1$ excluded?